# Relation between FFXIII and Final Fantasy Versus XIII?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

Well, I have finished FFXIII, and I have been seeing stuff about "Final Fantasy Versus XIII". Since the name includes "XIII", I assumed it was related to FFXIII (Lightning, Cocoon, ya know). But when I saw the trailer and some info, well, I can't make a connection at all!

What is the relation between these two games, if both include the XIII signature?

Comment: Not sure, but it looks good. http://uk.ps3.ign.com/objects/826/826846.html

Comment: btw, I thought that you might want to know that they are making XIII-2 if you don't already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the developers](http://uk.ps3.ign.com/articles/705/705978p1.html), FFXIII: Versus is set in the same universe as FFXIII, meaning they will share some common mythology. However, there will be no characters, worlds, or stories referenced between games, and Versus is neither a sequel nor a prequel to FFXIII.

Answer (score -1):

One thing I noticed about XIII and Versus XIII is that they both refer to the Goddess Etro. Perhaps thats how they are all linked.

Comment: Was Etro ever mentioned in FF13?  I only recall it coming up in FF13-2.